# Output a MySQL formatted string

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a query likes:

```
SELECT name FROM product WHERE id = 28;
```

The result is "HTC Desire HD"

I want this result to be replaced with XX in the string "I Like XX", after replacing, the string is "I Like HTC Desire HD"

Likes the PHP printf function, can I use MySQL to do that?

Comment: this is not ideal.use presentation language like php to do the formatting should be better

Comment: @ajreal: It seems about the same either way.  Similar to querying someone's full name as `SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)`.  Unless that's just bad practice I'm not aware of (I'm no expert on SQL).

Comment: is not the same.the formatted strings are meant for presentation let the presentation language to do the job

Comment: @ajreal PHP does not answer the question. You don't know the context. If you need a fully SQL report, you'll need pure SQL formatting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be:

```
select 'I Like ' || name from product where id = 28;
```

in regular SQL. I'm not entirely certain that will work in MySQL unless you have `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` configured, but the equivalent:

```
select CONCAT('I Like ', name) from product where id = 28;
```

should be fine.

Comment: I think in MySQL it's double pipes (`||`), as long as your database is set to `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` mode :-)  +1 !

Answer (score 4):

Like a [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)?

```
SELECT CONCAT('I Like ',name)
FROM   product
WHERE  id = 28;
```